# Variable not behaving as a global variable when using a form to call

Tags: javascript, forms

The following code consists of a form that is calling a function on submitting. var 'x' is a global variable but it doesnot behave like one. the value of x should actually go on increasing but it doesnt.(it just outputs 1 all the time) ps:i know things are missing from the form tag but it doesnt matter in this case.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var x=0;
function myform(){
x++;
alert(x); 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form name="form" method="post" onsubmit="return myform()">
<input />
<input type="submit"/> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because the form submits and the page reloads and the javascript starts over.... If you do not want the form to submit than you should be cancelling it. If you want it to submit, than you need to look at localstorage.

Comment: make myform `return false;` as its last line to stay on the page.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks it worked